# $|z_1+…+z_n|=n$ if and only if all the unit $z_i$ are equal

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Let $z_1,z_2,…,z_n$ be complex numbers of unit length. I want to prove that if the modulus of their sum $z$ is $n$, then they are equal.

My solution goes as follows. On the contrary, assume at least one pair $z_i,z_j$ are distinct so that the angle $\theta_{i,j}$ between them is not $0$. We have $z.z=n^2$ by hypothesis, where . is the dot product. On the other hand, $z.z=n+2\sum_{i\neq j}\cos\theta_{i,j}\lt n+2\binom {n}{2}=n^2$, a contradiction.

Is my solution correct? Is there a more direct proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally is profitable to look for ways to apply Cauchy-Schwarz.
$n=\big \vert z_1+…+z_n\big \vert= \big \vert \sum_{k=1}^n z_k\cdot 1\big \vert\leq \Big ( \sum_{k=1}^n \vert z_k\vert^2\Big )^\frac{1}{2} \cdot \Big ( \sum_{k=1}^n 1^2\Big )^\frac{1}{2}=  n^\frac{1}{2}\cdot  n^\frac{1}{2}=n$
$\implies z_1 = z_2 = \dots = z_n$

More succinctly:
$\mathbf z \propto \mathbf 1$ since $n=\big\vert\mathbf 1^*\mathbf z\big \vert \leq \big\Vert \mathbf z\big \Vert_2\big\Vert \mathbf 1\big \Vert_2=n$ by Cauchy-Schwarz which is met with equality.

Comment: Your basic argument that this is a case of using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is correct but surely your equation at the top must be wrong, you have $n=...\leq....$ there.

Comment: @SuzuHirose No.  I meant to use the $n$ as bookends to examine the "only if" part that OP asked about.  I ignored the "if" part of OP's question since it trivially holds.   There are different ways to write this but someone had to mention C-S Inequality.

Comment: Thanks, that’s a nice proof

Answer (score 4):

We write $z_{1}=\cos\theta_{1}+i\sin\theta_{1},....z_{n}=\cos\theta_{n}+i\sin\theta_{n}$ (since the modulus of each one is $1$).

Thus, $(\cos\theta_{1}+....+\cos\theta_{n})^{2}+(\sin\theta_{1}+....\sin\theta_{n})^{2}=n^{2}$

which gives $n+2((\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}+\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2})+.......)=n^{2}$

=$n+2(\cos(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})+........)=n^{2}$. The number of $\cos(\theta_{i}-\theta_{j})$ is $\dbinom{n}{2}$

and the only way to get $n^{2}$ is to have $\theta_{i}=\theta_{j}$ for all $i,j, i\neq j$ in which case we obtain:

$n+2\dbinom{n}{2}=n^{2}$. In any other case (i.e. if $\cos(\theta_{i}-\theta_{j})<1)$ for some $i,j$ we get a value smaller than $n^{2}$ and the equality fails. Therefore we must have $\theta_{1}=.....=\theta_{n}$ i.e.

$z_{1}=z_{2}=.....=z_{n}$

Comment: This argument is correct but I think it could be stated more clearly and also with the correct latex `\cos` for cosine.

Comment: OK I fixed it. Waiting for an upvote!!!

Comment: I've upvoted but you still have some wobbly subscripts there.

Comment: I must admit, I am not an expert in latex but I am getting better!

Comment: This is essentially in line with my own shorter solution, but thanks for sharing your slightly different proof

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The norm of the sum of two unit vectors is two if and only if they are equal. Then the $n$-dimensional case instantly follows:

$$|z_1 + \cdots + z_n| = n$$
if and only if all the unit $z_i$ are equal.

Comment: Nice. It might be good to elaborate on the base case of the induction though, the $n=2$ case

Comment: I guess this line of proof would be a rather tedious computation

Comment: If $u\cdot u=1$, and $v \cdot v =1$, then suppose $2^2=|u+v|^2=(u+v) \cdot (u+v) = 2 + 2 u \cdot v$. So $u \cdot v$ would need to equal 1, but then the angle between them is 0, hence $u=v$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left| z1+z2+z3+.....zn\right|\leqslant \left| z1\right| + \left|z2 \right|+ .....\left|zn \right|$  =n  with equality holding when the vectors z1,z2,...zn  are parallel.Since the equality holds the vectors are parallel and since they have the same module they are equal.

Comment: It might be useful to add the name of the result you've used (triangle inequality).

Comment: @koke what you wrote was just a rephrasing of the problem

Comment: Indeed the name of the inequality is the triangle inequality  extended to n numbers Concerning the rephrasing of the problem if you read my answer I prove that the vectors are parallel  (since the triangle inequality is in our case an equality)  and since the vectors  have the same lenght they are equal  No rephrasing

Comment: @koke that they are parallel and with the same length does not imply that they are equal, they might be in reverse directions. Anyway، any such claim as you wrote needs a proof, that’s exactly what the problem wants

Comment: OK I see your point Starting form the fact that the vectors are parallel and have the same length then if at least one of them was in reverse direction from amother vector then their sum  by th etriangle inequality would have a length  at most n-2 and not n